# Regex preg qoute mimic regex

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace

I am trying to mimic the functionality of `preg_qoute` without escaping the characters, `: ( ) < >`.

So far I have been able to come up with, `[.\\+*?[^\\]${}=!|]` and I would use it like below,

```
preg_replace('#[.\\+*?[^\\]${}=!|]#', '\\\\$0', '(hello)/(goodbye/(<still there>))');
```

The problem is it is **not** escaping the `/` character and I get an unescaped delimiter exception.

Any ideas?

Thanks.

Comment: It's not escaping the `/` because it is not defined in the set of characters..

Comment: Any help on that? I have tried `\/` but I can't get it working

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would write it out like this adding `/` and `-` to the set of characters. Although I am not clear why you want to mimic this function and leave the other characters unescaped.

```
preg_replace('~[.+*?^$\\|[\]{}=!/-]~', '\\\\$0', '. \ + * ? [ ^ ] $ { } = ! | - ( ) < > :');
```

Outputs

```
\. \ \+ \* \? \[ \^ \] \$ \{ \} \= \! \| \- ( ) < > :
```

Comment: I am trying to dynamically build regexes that handles named groups and such. Thank you big help, I tried voting up but it wouldn't let me.